# How to perform single-arm meta-analysis

Tags: r, meta-analysis, network-meta-analysis

I'm currently intending to perform a single-arm meta-analysis which study outcomes are: Objective Response Rate (ORR%), Disease Control Rate (DCR%), Duration of Response (DOR) in months, PFS in months, and Overall Survival (OS) in months. Should I do Meta-analysis for proportion?

1. If so, how to perform it? I believe RevMan and SPSS can't perform single-arm meta analysis, while I tried to use MetaAnalyst, Open Meta[analyst], OpenMEE, MetaXL, MIL, etc. but still clueless as how to perform them (#n.b.: MetaAnalyst can't run in my laptop). However, I can't manage to understand R and can't afford to buy STATA nor CMA. Can anyone please help about what and how to perform it?
2. If not, what kind of meta-analysis should I perform?
3. As far as I know, Open Meta[analyst] is developed from MetaAnalyst, while OpenMEE is another upgrade from Open Meta[analyst]. If MetaAnalyst can perform single-arm meta analysis, can OpenMEE do it?

Thank you, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to publish your research it must be of high quality, reproducible and expandable with analyses possibly recommended by reviewers. I recommend you to use R (maybe through RStudio). There are several nice MOOCs that can guide you. It is a very fruitful investment of your time, and a great asset for your CV. Otherwise, contact an author of a scholarly paper similar in scope to your work, and ask for his/her methodological support, while offering coauthorship in the eventual scholarly manuscript.